# Add content to existing notification android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm building the chat notification part of an app and the behaviour I'm willing to achieve is the following:

*user a receives a message from user b*

NOTIFICATION
 1 new message from B
 - hey there

*user a receives another message from user b*

NOTIFICATION
 2 new messages from B
 - hey there
 - how are you?

My notification by now looks like this:

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Utilities.NEW_MESSAGE_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_icon)
            .setLargeIcon(userImage)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .addAction(action)
            .setGroup(MY_GROUP)  
            .setContentTitle(my_title)
            .setContentText(data.get("body"))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                      .bigText(data.get("body")));
```

But using it in this way, the second notification will just completely overwrite the previous one.

Is there a way to achieve this without having to rebuild the notification from scratch (I mean without passing again the previous message, but just adding the new one to the already existing notification)?

Comment: You can do that with notify the same notification with same notification id with updated data.

Comment: @MayurRaval but in this way on the second notification I should pass to the notification builder, both the previous message ("hey there") and the new one ("how are you"), while I'd like to just add the second to the existing one

Comment: This is not how Android notifications work.. As @MayurRaval said, you have to post a new notification with the same ID to achieve 'update-like' behaviour.

Comment: Ok, thank you both for your answers!